# Scope problem with nested $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, twitter, scope, callback, jsonp

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=/…'+ query1 + '&callback=?',
  function(data) {
    alert('JSON data string 1 is: '+data); 
    $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=/…'+ query2 + '&callback=?', 
      function(data1) {
        alert('JSON data string 2 is: '+data1); 
        f2=data1; 
        f1=data; 
        for(var i=0; i "less than" f1.length; i++)
        {
          for(var j=0; j "less than" f2.length; i++)
          {
            if (f1[i] == f2[j])
            {
              common[c]=f1[i];
              c+=1;
            }
          }
        }
        $('#content').append(''+common.length+'');//this line is not working though....... 
    });
});
```

In this piece of the line

```
$('#content').append(''+common.length+'');
```

doesnt show the output actually it the page hangs

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't nest the calls.  You also avoid some memory issues where javascript maintains a copy of all local variables for every anonymous function.  By making the two calls separately you can also perform both calls at once instead of sequentially.

This is a better method if I understand your purpose.  Plus by polling gotA and gotB you can even make a nice little "waiting for A, waiting for B" notification for users.

Edit: Added for loop fix from previous answer.

```
var gotA, gotB;
var followingA, followingB;
function getCommonFollowers(user1, user2)
{
    gotA = false;
    gotB = false;
    jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=/…'+ user1 + '&callback=?', gotFollowersOfA );
    jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=/…'+ user2 + '&callback=?', gotFollowerOfB );
}
function gotFollowersOfA(data)
{
    followingA = data;
    gotA = true;
    if (gotB) {
        compareFollowersAB();
    }
}
function gotFollowersOfB(data)
{
    followingB = data;
    gotB = true;
    if (gotA) {
        compareFollowersAB();
    }
}
function compareFollowersAB()
{
    f2=followingA; 
    f1=followingB; 
    for(var i=0; i < f1.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j < f2.length; j++) {
            if (f1[i] == f2[j]) {
                //console.log("Adding f1[i]");
                common.push(f1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    $('#content').append(''+common.length+'');
}
```

Comment: thanks so much....this is a great way to approach the solution...using a flag...very nice:)..

Answer (score 2):

Your second for loop increments i instead of j.

You dont declare any of your vars which may lead to scope issues etc.

Can you paste your actual code, its a tough ask to expect anyone to diagnose the issue without your script.

Also create a demo of the issue at jsbin.com or pastebin.me while your at it.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [Great Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93210/great-turtle)'s recommendations, but since I tried it anyway, here's a modified version of your code that does work:

```
        var query1 = 'user1';
        var query2 = 'user2';
        var data;
        var data1; 
        var f1;
        var f2;
        var common = [];
        var c = 0;
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=' + query1 + '&callback=?', 
                function(data) { 
                console.log('JSON data string 1 is: ' + data); 
                $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json?screen_name=' + query2 + '&callback=?', 
                    function(data1) { 
                    console.log('JSON data string 2 is: ' + data1); 
                    f2=data1; 
                    f1=data; 
                    for(var i=0; i < f1.length; i++) {
                        for(var j=0; j < f2.length; j++) {
                            if (f1[i] == f2[j]) {
                                //console.log("Adding f1[i]");
                                common.push(f1[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $('#content').append(''+common.length+'');
                }); 
            });
        });
```

The main fix was that your 2nd for loop, as previously mentioned, used i++ instead of j++, so your loops were going crazy.

Note that I changed your alert calls to console.log, so make sure you're using Firefox with Firebug installed, or simply replace the console.log with your alert again.

Comment: I do not particularly like this answer because the two json requests are made synchronously and considering that this is also the langest part of the activity it should be executed asap and in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be with 'http://' ?

`$.getJSON('http://twitter.com...'`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable common outside the json functions.